# Windows 10 on a laptop: putting just the LCD to sleep without affecting other operating system tasks

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, dell-latitude, standby

I have a laptop (Dell Latitude E6430) that I am using to record video files 24/7 at a remote site. I would like for the laptop LCD screen to turn off after a few minutes of keyboard/touchpad disuse to conserve power. Operating system is Windows 10.

Settings are, left click START, scroll to Windows System Control Panel, left click on power options, set "Turn off display" to "5 minutes" for both "On battery" and "Plugged in", and set "Put the computer to sleep" to "Never" for both battery and plugged in. When the laptop starts recording video, after 5 minutes the display turns off, however video recording is also stopped at this point. I assume that the system has been put to standby. Note that video is not playing to the screen during the recording process. However, when "Turn off display" is set to "Never" the laptop will record video for weeks without interruption as it should.

How can I turn off just the LCD after a few minutes without putting the entire system to sleep/standby?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) I assume you have reached the Power Options "Advanced settings"? (2) Have you set both Sleep and Hibernate to Never? (3) Which Power plan are you using (Balanced, High performance etc)?

Comment: How certain are you that the system goes to standby? Have you checked Event Viewer? What does that show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per harrymc's comment above, the following actions resolved this: in the popup which opens after pressing the button "Change Advanced Power Settings" in the power options window, changing the settings for "sleep after" and "hibernate after" to "Never" resolved this. To do this scroll down to zero, and then go one more place and "Never" will appear in the window. Also changed the "turn off hard disk after" settings to "Never" as well for good measure. See screen grab below for further detail if needed,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible exactly as you think, since I don't use Windows that often.
With my laptop, I can use the display brightness buttons to turn the display brightness down so that it is effectively off at the darkest level.
However, the laptop is currently running ubuntu and I unfortunately have no way to run Windows there.
Maybe you can also find a third party software that can set the display brightness to zero.

Greetings
Johannes